# Serial voting should not be reversed when all of the posts belong to a single question

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Our community took ([or is indefinitely taking](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/18487)) a poll on our meta. The question has 14 answers, 12 of which are all posted by the same user. By the looks of it, some votes were reversed due to the serial voting detection mechanism.

It seems to me that "real" serial voting would occur across many questions. If one user posts 12 answers to the same question, it is perfectly reasonable to vote on all of them. It might even be reasonable to downvote ten of them and only upvote two.

Can we amend the logic for detecting serial voting to look wide instead of deep? In other words, can we modify it to detect patterns across many questions instead of triggering from a bunch of votes on a small handful of questions? Is there a reason why we wouldn't want to do this?

Comment: I personally think it shouldn't be possible to make a dupe of a closed question at all.