# "Yes, that solved my problem" forces me to acknowledge or reject all targets

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-suggestions

Here is what the "Yes, that solved my problem!" dialog looks like when there are multiple targets.

[image]

I clicked the button for experimental purposes, and you can [see what happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252031/254466). My only options are to either acknowledge, reject *both* targets, or ignore the dialog entirely. What if one of them solved the problem and the other one did not? That seems like a valid use case to me.

Give me a way to say, "Out of the many proposed duplicates, this one(s) solved my problem."

Comment: My vision if having radio button next to each possible duplicate in such case. This will require major change in the code behind the scenes, e.g. clearing the votes on the other dupes so not sure if it's really feasible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That also fundamentally assumes that there can be only one duplicate, contrary to the way the system works now.

Comment: @Servy it's kind of like accepted answer, that can be only one. It's based on the OP's decision and his alone. If we give OP such power, better give it all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But duplicates closure *isn't* like that, and I see no compelling reason to *make* it be that way. In the vast majority of cases it'd be removing helpful information.

Comment: @Servy but things are changing. Until this change, OP close vote was just a single vote without any power. Now it's binding. So another change seems possible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure it's *possible*.  I fail to see why it would possibly be *beneficial*.

Comment: @Woodface The OP has a binding close vote.  They don't have a binding reopen vote, or a binding vote to not close.  If they say that their question is answered the question is indeed instantly closed, regardless of how many close votes it has.

Comment: @Woodface They don't have a binding vote through the close vote dialog.  They have a button that they can click to instantly close the question.  It is effectively a binding (conditional) close vote.  If you *really* want to call it something different you can, but I don't see any reason not to call it a biding close vote.

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth, you *don't* have the power to reject *any* of the duplicates. Editing the question only hides the notice for you until another duplicate close vote comes in. The close votes do not disappear, and all of those targets would still appear in the final duplicate notice if it got closed as a duplicate anyways.

You're effectively asking for a single user to have the power to invalidate an existing close vote based on their opinions of whether something answers their question or not. That's a dangerous power to give away, especially considering users without even a proper understanding of our system can utilize this feature.

Comment: If four people close as a duplicate of one target, and a fifth guy decides to close as a duplicate of another target, the fifth guy is ignored (although his name, ironically, is attached to the question he didn't even vote for). It seems consistent then that if a single user can power close his own question as a dupe, that he have the power to choose *which one*.

Comment: Also, I can apparently power close my own question before anyone else comes along and votes. All I have to do is vote to close my own question, refresh the page, and click on the button. Why should someone else's vote change my ability to do this?

Comment: The fifth guy does not get ignored. His duplicate target would also appear in the list. *Any* duplicate vote active on the question at the time of closure will be displayed, no matter how many votes were cast for that particular target.

Comment: Has that changed recently? Sorry, I might have been misremembering. Perhaps I was thinking about the case where one user votes to close for one reason while four others vote to close as a dupe. My mistake.

Comment: @Rainbolt For the close reasons themselves, only the one with the most votes gets displayed, and for the custom off-topic reasons, only those sub-reasons with at least two votes on them get displayed under the main off-topic reason.

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, you are not *forced* to do anything. If neither of two options appeal to you, choose neither.

Also, it's not like this feature is taking something away from you that you had before. Previously, the most you could do was to vote (or not vote) as a duplicate of one of the posts; but all suggested duplicates would appear in the banner, even those with just 1 closevote of support. This is no different now.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that this feature was "taking something away" from anyone. I was suggesting an improvement. I take it you don't think it's an improvement.

Comment: @Rainbolt Retag your question as `[feature-request]` then to make clear that's what you're doing

Comment: This is a good point. We want to make it slightly annoying for users not to improve their questions if they might be a duplicate. What's the worst that will happen, they'll get confused and close their question, or they'll get confused and make the question better just to appease the dialogue box?

Answer (score -3):

As long as *one* of them solves your problem, then that's good enough.  You've solved your problem, and don't need any more help, and future readers will be able to solve their problem (if they have the same problem) by following the duplicates provided.

There's just no real compelling reason to be any more granular than that.

Comment: It's confusing to the user. That's bad UX in itself.

Comment: No compelling reason? You mean, other than the fact that we now have a dialog with no correct answer (in certain cases)?

Comment: @djechlin How is it confusing to the user?  Either their problem was solved, or it wasn't.  What's to be confused about?  Adding in a whole bunch of additional options, and trying to select applicable quesitons would dramatically *increase* the complexity of the UX, making it *more* confusing, not *less*.

Comment: @Rainbolt If your problem was solved by one of the proposed duplicates, then you can say that your problem was solved.  If none of the proposed duplicates solved your problem, then you can say so.  One of the two is always correct.

Comment: @servy The dialog says *"that solved my problem"* not *"my problem was solved"*.

Comment: @Rainbolt Okay, and did that collection of links solve your problem, or did it not solve your problem?  It's a simple problem with a simple answer, and always has exactly one correct answer.

Comment: @Servy I think you added some words in there.

Comment: @Rainbolt I replaced a pronoun with the specific noun it was referring to, yes.  Did you think that "that" was referring to something other than the collection of links provided?  If so, what did you assume "that" was referring to?

Comment: @Servy I didn't assume. I would like very much for it to be made explicit. (i.e., "*That* question solved my problem, and *that* question did not.") Judging by your earlier comment about how this would "dramatically" increase the complexity of the UI, you are probably imagining a series of checkboxes or some other complex mechanism. It doesn't have to be complex. It just needs to be *slightly* (not dramatically) more complex than it is now. The dialog could even randomly pick one of the two (or pick the one with more votes) and prompt the user with only one of the two. Be creative.

Comment: @Rainbolt And what if the question with the most votes wasn't the one that solved the problem?  What if they both solved the problem?  Your solution of "pick the question with the highest votes" is quite flawed.  Picking randomly seems even less likely to result in the correct set of questions being chosen.  And you still haven't provided any compelling reason to not act on the collection *as a collection*.  You have not given any reason to choose just one question instead of acting on all of them.

Comment: @Servy Alright. I agree that my "pick one" idea was flawed. It was offhand and in a comment. I'm saying that **one, the other or both** might be the one that solved my problem. So I should have the option to pick **one, the other, or both**. This is not complex logic.

Comment: @Rainbolt And why should we do that?  What is gained by spending the effort to make such a distinction?  And I dispute your claim that doing this isn't at all complex.  How would you design the UI to do this?  And keep in mind, you're comparing whatever you come up with with a single button, in terms of complexity, that's about as simple as it gets.

Comment: @Servy Responding to every single one of my comments with *"Why?"* isn't going to get you anywhere. Why? Because Foo. Why Foo? Because Bar. Why Bar? Why? Why?! WHY??!!!

Comment: @Rainbolt If you're going to continue to refuse to explain why you think you're proposed feature should be implemented, I'm going to continue to ask you why you think your proposed feature should be implemented.  Features aren't added, "just because".  What you're proposing is a fairly radical change, it would be a lot of work for the developers and add quite a bit of complexity to the page.  If there is no compelling reason to do this, then it shouldn't be done.  If you can provide some benefits that would be greater than those costs, then it could be worth doing.

Comment: @Servy When you acknowledge the two explanations I've already provided, I'll consider providing a third. This behavior of "dismiss your explanation, exaggerate my own" is absurd and not at all productive.

Comment: @Rainbolt So you're saying that we should add this behavior because you didn't understand that "that solved my problem" means that the information in one of the links solved your problem?  You feel that the only way to solve that misunderstanding on your part is to add an entirely new UI in which the questions that helped you solve your problem can be checked off?  Personally, I don't think it's unclear at all, but if you *really* think it is, then at most it would only warrant changing the text of the button.

Comment: @Servy the whole point of adding this banner with friendly buttons is making it more user friendly. I agree it should be kept simple even in such edge case of more than one dupe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I urge you to write a sensible answer to that effect. "I like it simple more than I care about having a bunch of choices, so keep it the way it is." I think that servy is in complete denial that there is any benefit at all, but I can tell that you see at least see *some*.

Comment: @Rainbolt I didn't say there couldn't possibly be any benefit.  I asked you to explain what you feel the benefits are.  The only benefits that I can see certainly don't outweigh the problems.  You need to be able to do more than just assert that benefits exist.  You are expect to actually explain what the benefits are.  If you're incapable of even explaining what the benefits are, then it's a pretty strong indication that they aren't compelling.  And before any discussion about whether the benefits are worth it can be had, we need to first be on the same page as to what the benefits are.

Comment: @Rainbolt might pull something up at some point, but you can also write a self answer. :-)

Comment: Servy, you're lecturing us on why we should not have been confused and why it was clear all along. That's not how UX works. Period.

Comment: @djechlin No, I'm saying that making it more complex and confusing is not the appropriate response to "it's confusing". If the OP was asking for the UI to be made *simpler*, for things to be re-worded, etc. then those would all be valid response to "it's too confusing".  Do you honestly think that adding in the ability to select which of the selected close duplicates they think should be kept/removed would make the UI *less* confusing? I never said that that anyone shouldn't be confused; your claim that I said otherwise is just wrong. I said that the OP's change doesn't make it less confusing.