# Multiple "That solved my question" suggestions only showing button once

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-suggestions

I posted a question on Workplace SE and received a suggestion for a post where my question was already answered. This did not answer my question, so I chose "my question is different" and edited my question.

Then I got another suggestion that did solve the problem, but there was no longer a "That solved my problem!" button.

Related to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252035/yes-that-solved-my-problem-forces-me-to-acknowledge-or-reject-all-targets).

Comment: [link to question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55545/why-is-it-bad-to-compare-salaries-among-peers) for those interested

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in build 3754 on MSE/MSO, and build 2877 on other sites.

Previously, to determine whether to prompt the OP with "That solved my problem!", the code checked to see if the *oldest* duplicate flag was newer than the OP's latest edit, which would always be false once the OP has edited. Now, we see if there has been a new duplicate flag target after the OP's latest edit (i.e., a new duplicate flag with a target that wasn't previously used before the OP's latest edit).

This way, if another user adds a duplicate flag with a previously seen target, the OP won't be pestered again with the prompt.