# No "That solve my problem" button for not yet closed question

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

[My question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288323/339911) not yet closed as dup, but I can't see <kbd>That solve my problem</kbd> button in the header:

> [image: dup]

> [image: no-dup]

Where is the button?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was removed because you edited the question. (Note, there is no "This did not solve my problem" button, only a link to edit the question.)

When you edit the question, it cause the buttons to disappear, and as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267559/152859), they will be displayed again only if a new dupe flag will be cast after the edit, pointing to a different question.